# pandas groupby and boolean selection

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I often end up doing things like this in `pandas`:

```
s2 = s1.groupby(level=1).sum()
s2 = s2[s2>25]
```

In words, I do some `groupby` operation and then want to keep only results that meet some condition for the result.

Is there a way to do with in one line? More specifically, is it possible to do this without creating the series and then doing the Boolean selection in a second step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.loc` + `lambda`

Serise

```
df.groupby('name').a.sum().loc[lambda x: x>20]
Out[492]: 
name
Chn     84
Fra    165
Ind     71
```

Dataframe

```
df.groupby('name').a.sum().to_frame().loc[lambda x: x['a']>20]
Out[490]: 
        a
name     
Chn    84
Fra   165
Ind    71
```

DataInput

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Ind','Chn','SG','US','SG','US','Ind','Chn','Fra','Fra'],'a':[5,6,3,4,7,12,66,78,65,100]})
```

Comment: Interesting, haven't seen this before. Found the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable

Answer (score 9):

**Assuming `s1` is a `pandas.Series`**

1. You can pass `level` to [**`pd.Series.sum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html)
2. [**`pd.Series.compress`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.compress.html) is handy

---

```
s2.sum(level=1).compress(lambda s: s.gt(25))
```

---

**Assuming `s1` is a `pandas.DataFrame`**
*And that there is a column names `'col'`*

```
s.sum(level=1).query('col > 25')
```

Comment: Finding a new way :-)

Comment: Both y'all's answers dropped some mad knowledge bombs in this question. (Y)